# encoding ÆØÅ Danish language read and write it correct UTF8

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

Im trying to edit a file that is on danish, with ÆØÅ letters.

But i'm doing somthing wrong, i can ad a line with the correct letters, but it seams like im not reading the excisting lines correct, and therefore I get "2. P�skedag" insted of "2. Påskedag"

My code is

---

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string filePath = @"C:\Users\tib5ka\Desktop\FællesVagtplan-filer\sheet001.htm";

        string[] lines  = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
           // lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("INFOBAR :", "<marquee>Det er froååkosttid.</marquee>");


        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: The file is not encoded in utf8.  Delete it from your machine so it can do no further harm.

Answer (score 0):

after hours of search I'd finaly found the solution just as a posted my question in here.

It was my encoding in the read line that was wrong.

It shoud be `System.Text.Encoding.Default`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string filePath = @"C:\Users\tib5ka\Desktop\FællesVagtplan-filer\sheet001.htm";

        string[] lines  = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
           lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("INFOBAR :", "<marquee>Det er froååkosttid.</marquee>");


        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. It must match whatever the encoding of the input file is. In your case this worked, but note for future reference that if the input file was in a different encoding to the default for your system you would have had a mojibake problem to that in your question.

Comment: Unless you need the code to use the default encoding on the system that it runs on, it would be better to identify the encoding of the file and use that. Better yet, if you are reading an HTML document, use an HTML library. It might find a meta charset declaration and use that. And, it certainly wiould help you parse the HTML.